# JavaScript custom module is not working, some help please

Tags: javascript, module

I'm making a JavaScript Module that imports a popup box and the import doesn't seem to work. I need some help making my javascript program work

https://github.com/Daniel4-Scratch/JuiceBox

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script>
import {juiceBox} from 'module/pack.js';
import {juiceBoxPopup} from 'module/pack.js';

juiceBox() // Import it
juiceBoxPopup("Hello!", "Hi my name it bob", "Copyright me") // Launch it
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="module/pack.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<button id="jb-btn">Open Box</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where have you placed the pack.js file?  The code needs it to be in a sub-folder called "module" - is that where you have it?

Comment: Yes I have it in a folder in another repo on glitch.com

Comment: Look in the console, there's an error message there. :-)

Comment: :/ JavaScript console disabled Shared computer.

Comment: Look in the console of your _browser_ (Developer Tools (F12) -> Console)

Comment: I swear it's disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You can't use `import` in a script, only in a module. To indicate your inline code is a module, you need to add `type="module"` to the `script` tag:

   ```
    <script type="module">
    import {juiceBox} from "module/pack.js";
    // ...
   ```
2. Module paths in browsers (unless you use an import map) must start with `.` or `..` or be absolute URLs. So in your case, `./module/pack.js`.

[Working on plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UvCDprVX4uKIf6FB?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview)

Comment: Hmm, It doesn't seem to work, I'll try different way. Thanks tho :)

Comment: @Daniel - There was a second problem. :-) I've updated the answer.